# How to store multiple database columns into an array with Linq2Sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

I have to work with multiple SQL Server tables that generally look like this:

```
int id_this, int id_that, ..., double Value1, double Value2, ..., double Value96
```

I know this sucks, but I can't change it. What I want to do now is to define some class like

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id_This { get; set; }
    public int Id_That { get; set; }
    ...
    public double Value[];
}
```

The Value-Array being a property of course, but I think you get the idea.

The question is, how to get the 96 columns into the array as painlessly as possible.

I could do that with a plain SqlDataReader, since DataRow allows indexed access, but I wonder if I could declare some attributes or write some minimum amount of code to use the class directly with LINQ2SQL.

As a minimum, I would like to do

```
dataContext.ExecuteQuery<Foo>("SELECT * FROM Foo");
```

Comment: In case you wonder about the "96". There is one value for each quarter hour of the day :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ooh, that is... nice? The `DataContext` methods always expect an entity type; there is no `ExecuteReader`, which is a pain (but understandable, as it wants to behave as an ORM). To be honest, I would be tempted to use ADO.NET for the guts against this table, but if you have mapped the wide table to the `DataContext` you should be able to use either regular C# or reflection.

Since the number doesn't change, unless you have multiple tables I'd just bite the bullet and write some ugly code:

```
Foo foo = new Foo { Id_This = obj.Id_This, Id_That = obj.Id_That,
    Values = new double[] {obj.Value1, obj.Value2, ... } };
```

If you have multiple tables... reflection, perhaps optimised via `Expression`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
class FooUgly
{
    public int IdThis { get; set; }
    public int IdThat { get; set; }
    public double Value1 { get; set; }
    public double Value2 { get; set; }
    public double Value3 { get; set; }
}
class Foo
{
    public int IdThis { get; set; }
    public int IdThat { get; set; }
    public double[] Values { get; set; }
    public Foo() { }
    internal Foo(FooUgly ugly)
    {
        IdThis = ugly.IdThis;
        IdThat = ugly.IdThat;
        Values = extractor(ugly);
    }
    // re-use this!!!
    static readonly Func<FooUgly, double[]> extractor =
        ValueExtractor<FooUgly, double>.Create("Value", 1, 3);
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        FooUgly ugly = new FooUgly { IdThis = 1, IdThat = 2, Value1 = 3, Value2 = 4, Value3 = 5 };
        Foo foo = new Foo(ugly);
    }
}
static class ValueExtractor<TFrom,TValue>
{
    public static Func<TFrom, TValue[]> Create(string memberPrefix, int start, int end)
    {
        if(end < start) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFrom), "source");
        List<Expression> vals = new List<Expression>();
        for(int i = start ; i <= end ; i++) {
            vals.Add(Expression.PropertyOrField(param, memberPrefix + i));
        }
        Expression arr = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(TValue), vals);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFrom, TValue[]>>(arr, param).Compile();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the prompt answer. I especially like the idea with the reusable Expression.